# Kubernetes cronjob to recycle a specific pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-cronjob, kubernetes-cluster

I am a recent Kubernetes user and would like to know if there is any way to create a cronjob that allows me to delete a specific pod from my cluster. After deleting it, I know it will be recreated and that's exactly what I want ... a refresh.

It is possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes (you will probably need to use the [Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/#api-client-libraries) or maybe script `kubectl rollout restart`).  What have you already tried, and what problems are you encountering?

Comment: I actually use crontab, but not to restart pods, but to make some copies for AWS S3, for example. I created a shell script to manually recycle when necessary, but I was unable to run it from a cronjob. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @AcacioDemetrio A Kubernetes cronjob creates a new job on a time-based schedule which in turn creates a pod. The pod runs to completion and exits and is cleared off. This could possibly address your need. I'm not too clear on why you want to recreate a pod but what I will suggest is that you read up on the different types of Kubernetes workloads and most likely you will find one to suit your needs.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [Kubernetes CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/). They work similarly to a regular cronjob, except each invocation creates a pod which is scheduled on an arbitrary node within the cluster rather than on a consistent one (unless you use the [Affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/) mechanics within Kubernetes).

Since a CronJob creates a pod and a pod can contain arbitrary code, I'll leave the final process of wiring this up as an exercise for the reader, but a good place to start would be the [Bitnami kubectl Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/kubectl) which can take advantage of in cluster authentication using [Service Accounts](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/) and [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/).

Lastly, what you're asking to do sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You may want to take a step back and think about whether or not a different approach or design pattern might work better here.